# Error in Json Data : Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

### **What is it about ?**

I am adding the elements in an array and finally trying to convert that array into Json. Below is the code.

```
$SubCategoryList = array();

array_push($SubCategoryList, 
            array(
                'SubCategoryID' =>  1,
                'FirstName'   =>  'First Name',
                'LastName'    =>  'Last Name',
            ));
array_push($SubCategoryList, 
            array(
                'SubCategoryID' =>  2,
                'FirstName'   =>  'First Name2',
                'LastName'    =>  'Last Name2',
            ));
```

**The above gives below mentioned output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [SubCategoryID] => 1
            [FirstName] => First Name
            [LastName] => Last Name
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [SubCategoryID] => 2
            [FirstName] => First Name2
            [LastName] => Last Name2
        )

)
```

**Below is the code used for converting the array into Json.**

```
<script>
     var subCategoriesList = {{ json_encode($SubCategoryList) }};
</script>
```

**and Finally json gives below output. Which can be seen in View source**

```
var subCategoriesList = [{&quot;SubCategoryID&quot;:1,&quot;FirstName&quot;:
&quot;First Name&quot;,&quot;LastName&quot;:&quot;Last Name&quot;},
{&quot;SubCategoryID&quot;:2,&quot;FirstName&quot;:&quot;First Name2&quot;,
&quot;LastName&quot;:&quot;Last Name2&quot;}];
```

**Question**

> Why it gives " in the json data ?

Comment: It is not completely clear what the problem is. In JSON [both key in pair and string value are quoted](http://json.org/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The JSON string uses quotes to show where a value starts and ends in basic terms.

Give

```
 var subCategoriesList = {!! $SubCategoryList !!};
```

a go. This will echo out an unescaped string for json.